# Is there a bug in Pick?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I wanted to use the `Pick` function with a condition. But there seems to be an issue here. Take a look at this:

```
selection = {0,1.2,3,0.,5};
Pick[{1,2,3,4,5},selection,elem_ /; elem =!= 0]
```

In *Mathematica* 8 it will give `{1,2,3,4,5}` instead of `{2,3,4,5}`. Please note, that the `Pick` function works nicely with

```
Pick[{1,2,3,4,5},selection,elem_ /; elem === 0]
```

Giving `{1}` as a result. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Relevant discussion on MathGroups: [`Pick` confusion and a special case of `Pick` with `SparseArray`](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/sBEkL9DwQqE/KAk2V8ZrQ6MJ).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This confused me as well, but using `Trace` revealed what is going on:

```
Trace@Pick[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, selection, elem_ /; elem =!= 0]

{{selection,{0,1.2,3,0.,5}},
 Pick[{1,2,3,4,5},{0,1.2,3,0.,5},elem_/;elem=!=0],
 {{0,1.2,3,0.,5}=!=0,True},
 {1,2,3,4,5}}
```

The key is the 4th line: note that the pattern is applied to the *full list*, at [level 0](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LevelsInExpressions.html).  The full list `selection` does match (because it is not structurally equivalent to 0) thus the full first argument is picked out.

The reason why we don't see this behavior with `Equal` (i.e. `==`) is that `{0, 1.2, 3, 0., 5} != 0` stays unevaluated.

(I did not find a way to restrict at which levels `Pick` operates, but it is possible to tweak the pattern instead, e.g. `elem_?NumericQ/;elem=!=0`, possibly with a performance hit.)

Comment: Does it mean that the `patt` in `Pick[list, sel, patt]` is **not** mapped over `list` and `sel` in this case? That is contradicting the help, I think.

Comment: @István It seems that `Pick` compares `list` and `sel` at every level, successively, including level 0.  Once a level matches, it picks everything from there.  If it doesn't, it looks at deeper levels.  Another example would be `Pick[{1, 2, {x, y, z}}, {1, 2, {a, b, c}}, a_ /; Length[a] == 3]`.  The full list is picked. If we change `1, 2` to `1, 2, 3` in both lists to make them length 4, only the last element will be picked.

Comment: Thank Szabolcs. One has to be really careful with the patterns as of course - thinking about it - everything is totally logical as elem_ matches a list in toto. I forgot to put in a Filter as you suggested. One might wish for a levelspec, but then you should probably turn to Cases anyway.

Comment: @gwr I agree that it's really confusing.  If it weren't for `Trace`, I would have believed it was a bug ...

Comment: Then I really wonder why Pick does not have a 4th argument for level specification...

Comment: @Szabolcs I do find confusing that Cases will work with the pattern not having to use the ?NumericQ test. So it is really the levelspec that is misleading. How good that Mathematica is an interpreted language ;-)

Comment: @gwr It seems `Cases` looks *only* at level 1 by default. In contrast to `Pick`, it does accept a level specification though, so we can force it to look at level 0 (using `{0}` as the last argument).  `Cases` is different in that once an element has matched, it will still look at its sub-elements: `Cases[{{1, 2}, {3, {4, 5}}}, _List, {1, Infinity}]`.

Comment: @Szabolcs +1. As to `Cases`: "once an element has matched, it will still look at its sub-elements" - this actually happens the other way around: `Cases` uses a depth-first traversal (which causes some [other effects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700934/why-is-cases-so-slow-here-are-there-any-tricks-to-speed-it-up/) as well), so it sees the parts before it sees the expression as a whole.

Comment: Maybe, an alternative way to avoid level 0 matches could be to add  that condition explicitly in the pattern: `elem_ /; elem =!= 0 && elem =!= selection`?

Answer (score 19):

Here is a version which avoids any extra performance overhead associated with `Condition` etc:

```
Pick[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, selection, Except[_List | 0]]
```

I did not benchmark, but for large lists I'd expect it to be significantly faster than the versions based on `Condition` and / or `PatternTest`.

Comment: `Except[selection | 0]` also works.

Comment: @kguler Yes, but I think this might be slower, since `_List` pattern must be faster to match.

Comment: Yes...I was trying to avoid mis-picks when `selection` contains lists.

Comment: @kguler Yes, I agree, it is better in that sense.

Answer (score 6):

**Edit**: Assuming that you do not differ between 0 and 0.

The unequal sign is !=

```
Pick[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, selection, elem_ /; elem != 0]
```

gives

> {2, 3, 5}

Alternatively you can use the True selection mechanism:

```
 Pick[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, !PossibleZeroQ[#] & /@ selection]
```

Comment: Thank you, Markus, but I wanted to explicitedly make a difference between a Null-entry as in a sparse array and a numerical Value of 0. That is why I used =!= instead of !=.

Comment: @gwr: If your goal is to find the elements which are explicitly in the sparse array, you can use `DeleteCases[#[[1,1]]&/@ArrayRules[yoursparsearray],Verbatim[_]]` or, if the array might be multi-dimensional, `DeleteCases[#[[1]]&/@ArrayRules[yoursparsearray],{Verbatim[_]...}]`