# Extracting information from list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a huge list that looks like this:

```
list = {8, 12, 201, 0.001, 3, 7, 100 
  (InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 0.0018}},"<>"][2916/35] + 
   InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 0.0018}}, "<>"][2916/35]), 
  23, 44, 11, -0.002}
```

I want to extract only the numbers, specifically the numbers around 10. I tried using this `Select[list,  _?(7 <= # <= 13 &)]` but it returns an empty list. I think this happens because the list has both numbers and the `100 (InterpolatingFunction...` that I want to ignore. I would also be happy just to extract ALL numbers hence ignoring the `100(InterpolatingFunction...` elements.

Could you give me some tip please?

Comment: You can use `Select[..., NumberQ[#] && 7 <= # <= 13 & ]`

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes it!
Should I delete the question?

Comment: You should never delete a question because you got an answer (only if your question was over-the-top stupid). It may be useful to others as well.

Comment: Why is that `InterpolatingFunction`there in the first place? Wouldn't you like to have that evaluated to a real number?

Comment: @Sjoerd: `list` comes as result of integrating a system using `NDSolve` considering around 4000 combinations of parameters. Some of those combinations do not yield a solution for the integration..
If possible, yes, I would like to have it evaluated to a real number, but the numerical integration doesn't finish until the endtime I allocated, and the endtime of the `InterpolatingFunction` is far from the desired (e.g. 0.018429 out of the desired 83.3).

Comment: @sosi OK, I see.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Select` wants a function as second argument, not a pattern. You can either use `Cases` or `Select` with a pure function:

```
Cases[list, _?(7 <= # <= 13 &)]

Select[list, (7 <= # <= 13)&]
```

Comment: One more thing:

if I want to select the elements of another list 

`otherlist={{1/10,1,1/100,10},{1/100,1,1/100,10},...}` 

that were used as arguments to obtain 

`list={8,12,201,0.001,3,7,100(InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,0.0018}},"<>"][2916/35]+InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,0.0018}},"<>"][2916/35]),23,44,11,-0.002}`

I thought I could use `Pick[otherlist,list,NumberQ[#]&&7<=#<=13&]`. Yet, it isn't working and returns that both lists have incompatible shapes. But both lists have the same length..

Comment: @Sosi: same problem the other way round: `Pick` wants, as `Cases`, a pattern, not a function. `Pick[otherlist,list,_?(NumberQ[#]&&7<=#<=13&)]` should work, if both lists really have the same structure. Something that might be a problem is that `Pick` applies the check to all levels of `list`, so depending on what exactly is the content you might see the shapes-warning. It then probably is better to create a "selection" list independently: `Pick[otherlist, (NumberQ[#] && 7 <= # <= 13) & /@ list]`

Comment: I had tried your first suggestion before, but was getting that structure error. The second suggestion works perfectly, I had not thought about using a map! Thanks!

Comment: @Sosi: here is another [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4946/169) which has more information about what I think is the deeper reason for the "incompatible shapes" warning, in case you are interested...