# Why doesn't this pattern work?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, pattern-matching, counting

I want the in-built function `Count` to count the elements in a list which are greater than a value.

Example:

```
Count[{1, 1, 2, 3}, (# > 1.5) &]
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Inverse of [(21206)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21206/121); variant of [(18054)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18054/121); beware of [(1699)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1699/121).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanksfor the comment. ;)

Comment: You're welcome.  By the way I realize that the close text on this one is a bit dismissive: "simple," "easily," but that is not *my* intent.  I could instead close this as a duplicate of one of the linked questions in the comment above if you would prefer.  Also the community may weigh in and decide to reopen it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'd vote to open since the function vs. pattern issue is a common mistake for beginner/intermediate MMA users, and I've yet to see a simple Q&A that addresses the issue as this one does.

Comment: @bobthechemist Did you ever cast a reopen vote?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yep.  the system won't let me try again (says I've already done so).  Not sure if I was voted down or if there's a quirk somewhere.

Comment: @bobthechemist I chose to employ moderator control to reopen this.  The original close-voters will not be able to vote again, just as you were not, but if a different set of users believes this should be closed and votes accordingly I will not contravene again.

Answer (score 12):

Your second argument is a function instead of a pattern.

```
Count[{1, 1, 2, 3}, _?(# > 1.5 &)]
```

Comment: Ups... Many thanks ;)

Comment: @Fred Simons Dear Fred, could you please kindly comment the following. The function `Select` is quite close to `Count` by its functionality. However, it recognizes the pattern argument in the form given in the above question, that is, just `#>1.5&` as follows: `Select[{1, 1, 2, 3}, (# > 1.5 &)]` returns `{2, 3}`. What is the difference between these two cases?

Comment: Check Mr. Wizard's comment to the OP. Specifically the first link.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch please see [(88220)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88220/121)

Comment: Dear @Alexei. I was out for some days, so I am a bit late in replying. In the mean time you have already got the link to Mr. Wizard's answer. I can only add that for me, Select and Count are not not so close, still apart from the fact that the first one uses a criterion function and the second one a pattern. Count can be used on any level: `Count[{{1,2},3,4}, _Integer, 2]`. This cannot be done with Select, that works only on level 1.

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard Thank you, I've got it.

Comment: @ Fred Simons  Thank you. That was my point that these two functions, though looking close from the first glance, are in reality different. Now I understand.

Comment: @Alexei when you separate the `@` symbol from the username you defeat the automatic notification.  Use e.g. `@FredSimons` (all one word) or at least the first three letters, e.g. `@Fred`.  The author of the post you comment under is notified automatically, so you don't actually need that here; the system may strip it if you use it in fact.

Answer (score 5):

In V10.0+ you can stick with functions:

```
CountsBy[{1, 1, 2, 3}, (# > 1.5) &][True]
```