# Why is there a difference when formulating patterns for Select and FirstPosition?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, filtering, language-design

```
Select[{1, 2, 4, 7, 6, 2}, # > 2 &]
```

Gives {4, 7, 6}. OK!

So one should think that the following would work:

```
myList = {-2, -1, 0, 1, 2};
FirstPosition[myList, # > 0 &]
```

But this fails. The correct command is

```
myList = {-2, -1, 0, 1, 2};
FirstPosition[myList, _?(# > 0 &)]
```

But why on earth do we have to use different syntax for those two cases??? 
Why is the `_?` necessary?

As it was commented by MarcoB:

`Select` takes a criterion function, while `FirstPosition` takes a pattern instead.

Can someone give a for dummies explanation what is the difference between both? Literally I would say a criterion is a pattern and a pattern is a criterion...

Comment: `Select` takes a *criterion function* as an argument, not a pattern; `FirstPosition` takes a pattern instead. You are converting the criterion function from `Select` into a conditional pattern. On the other hand, `Cases` is similar to `Select` in functionality, but it takes a pattern argument instead. That's just how those functions were designed!

Comment: But don't you aggree that is is very confusing? Why is it necessary  to have  criterion function and patterns. I don't even understand the difference!

Comment: I may agree that it is confusing at first, and of course it is not *necessary*, but in my opinion it is *convenient*, since it gives you two ways to achieve more or less the same goal, i.e. more flexibility.

Comment: Because both are convenient and have their uses. e.g. `Cases[list, {x_, x_}]` can be nicer, than say, `Select[list, First@#==Last@#&]` when we're talking about a list of pairs of numbers.

Comment: `Select[]` came waay before `FirstPosition[]`. Now, why they chose to pattern `FirstPosition[]` after `Cases[]` rather than `Select[]` is a question for the language designers.

Comment: FWIW, you could also do `FirstPosition[myList, _?Positive]` if you're allergic to the slots.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. makes sense, given that `Position` also takes patterns. Also `SelectFirst` and `FirstCase`  are things too.

Comment: Ah, all these newfangled syntactic diabetes functions… sadly they are still not present in my *gedanken* version, @LLlAMnYP. :)

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. actually I'm begin to understand OPs confusion from a different angle. We have `Select` with criterions and `Cases` with patterns to get the elements of a list. We have `Position` with patterns to get the indices. Where's my `CriterionPosition` with criterions??? Also, what's a "*gedanken* version"?

Comment: Maybe in version 11: Kitchen Sink Edition.

Comment: Related: [(7688)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7688/121), [(18054)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18054/121)

Comment: Let me edit my question...

Comment: Regarding your last question: a function is something that takes arguments and returns a value.  In `Select` you need to use a function that returns `True` or `False`.  A pattern is like a "regex for expressions", and can be used in pattern matching functions as well as definitions.  Go through the first few sections in [Patterns](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PatternsOverview.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question might end up closed as it is hard to know what was in the minds of the language designers in every case.  However I think a reasonable answer can be given here so I shall try.

The high-level *Mathematica* language is arguably built on pattern matching.  It it therefore natural that many functions also use, operate on, or work with patterns.  For example [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html), [`Count`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Count.html), [`Position`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html), [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html), [`Switch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Switch.html), [`Collect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Collect.html), [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) and [standard definitions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForFunctions.html) all natively use patterns.  Patterns allow a generally way to express a specification.

Since one can make any *Boolean test function* into a pattern using [`PatternTest` or `Condition`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1835/121) these may be considered a subset of pattern matching however they have their own benefits and conventions:

- They are easily applicable in a procedural style of programming, e.g. they fit naturally into constructs like [`If`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html), [`Which`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Which.html), etc.
- They combine with Boolean operators such as [`And`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/And.html), [`Or`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Or.html), [`Xor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Xor.html), [`Not`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Not.html), etc.

Since *Mathematica* uses a multi-paradigm language it is entirely reasonable for it to have functions dedicated to the use of Boolean test functions *as well as* its own pattern matching.  [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) is one such function.  Note that it lacks the *levelspec* of the more general [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) which I believe is in keeping with the style of programming it is primarily intended for.  It should be thought of as a *specialized* function.  Your question could perhaps be recast as "Why isn't there a "`BooleanPosition`" function?" With the explosion of functions in recent versions I would not be surprised if one appears, but really it is not necessary as it could be simply constructed from the existing `Position` function.

In summary patterns and Boolean test functions coexist in *Mathematica*; it is up to the user to choose the programming style and supporting functions that suit him and his application.