# How to use `Except[]` inside of `Pick[]`

Tags: pattern-matching

```
Pick[{1, 2}, {0, 1}, Except[0]]
```

returns `{1, 2}`, the first element of which I did expect to be excluded. What is the thing I don't understand?!

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59272/pick-bug-level-0-matching

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works:

```
Block[{Pick}, Thread@Pick[{1, 2}, {0, 1}, Except[0]]]
```

This is due to the fact that `Pick[1,0,Except[0]]` also works and gives `Sequence[]`. It appears, the pattern is working first on the whole expression. As `{0, 1}` matches `Except[0]`, it gives true and the corresponding element is the entire list `{1, 2}`.

Another quick workaround is this:

```
Pick[{1, 2}, {0, 1}, Except[0, Except[_List]]]
```

Here's a test to illustrate my PS:

```
Pick[{1, 2*x}, {0, x + 2}, Except[0, patt_ /; AtomQ[patt]]]
```

The internal forms of the list and selector are:

```
{1, Times[2,x]}
{0, Plus[2,x]}
```

As you can see, the nesting of the structures is identical, but the heads differ. Nonetheless, `Pick` disregards the fact that `Times` and `Plus` are not the same and returns `{2 x}`. IMO, maybe `Pick` is in over its head with generality.

PS
As Szabolcs comments, this was already discussed in the dupe + linked Q. I might add to the discussion, that since `Pick` is a very general function, that's designed to work on (1) arbitrarily shaped nested structures, and (2) the heads of which are not necessarily `List`, there is some logic, that the easy way out is to go through a top-level first, complete-expression first search routine. It, of course, has some caveats, such as this one.

Comment: +1 So `Except` *does* work. It's just thrown by the sequence functionality.

Comment: `Pick[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 0, 2}, Except[0 | _List]]` also works. (+1)

Comment: As does `Pick[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 0, 2}, Except[0, _Integer]]`

Comment: @kglr Your comment received 7 upvotes.  Please turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: @QuantumDot The thread has been closed, as you can see. I agree, that `Except[0 | _List]` is cleaner than `Except[0, Except[_List]]`. If you feel sufficiently strongly about this, you're welcome to edit it into the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like `Except` doesn't work in `Pick` pattern matching.  Here's a workaround.

```
Pick[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 0, 2}, _?(# != 0 &)]
```

> {2, 4}

Or similar to the form in [Pick](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html): Possible Issues (last example)

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4};
selector = {0, 1, 0, 2};
newSelector = Map[MatchQ[#, Except[0]] &, {0, 1, 0, 2}];
Pick[list, newSelector]
```

> {2, 4}