# Problem using Position applied on matrix with Infinity elements

Tags: pattern-matching

Am I doing something wrong here?

```
 m = {{Infinity, Infinity, Infinity}, {Infinity, 1, 2}, {Infinity, 2, 3}};
 Position[m, 1]
 (*{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 1}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 1, 1}}*)
```

What is the above? I can get correct position by

```
m = {{Infinity, Infinity, Infinity}, {Infinity, 1, 2}, {Infinity, 2, 3}};
Position[m, 1, {2}]
(*{{2, 2}}*)
```

But why it only affect the value `1`?

```
m = {{Infinity, Infinity, Infinity}, {Infinity, 1, 2}, {Infinity, 2, 3}};
Position[m, 3]
(* {{3, 3}} *)
```

If I remove `Infinity`, then I can find position of `1` ok, without using `{2}`

```
m = {{9, 9, 9}, {9, 1, 2}, {9, 2, 3}};
Position[m, 1]
(* {{2, 2}} *)
```

Why does it behave different with `1`? And what does this `{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 1}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 1, 1}}` mean?

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Don't know why it gives the error.  Oddly enough, `Position[N@m, 1.0]` gives the correct answer.

Comment: Related: [(4946)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4946/121), [(22948)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22948/121)

Comment: ... also related: [Why Infinity /. _?(# < 6 &) -> 0 replaces Infinity with ComplexInfinity?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65910/125).

Comment: @kguler Even closer relation!  I forgot about that one.  This is almost a duplicate of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Position`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html) is a pattern matching function, and pattern matching is performed on (something close to) the [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) of an expression.  Therefore when designing patterns, and especially when debugging them, the first thing to do is to look at the `FullForm` of the expression(s) you are working with.  In this case:

```
Infinity // FullForm
```

> ```
> DirectedInfinity[1]
> ```

This expression is not atomic:

```
Infinity // AtomQ
```

> ```
> False
> ```

It is therefore accessible (or exposed) to pattern matching, and the `1` inside it is discovered by `Position`.

Note: some atomic expressions are overloaded to partially work with patterns.  For examples please see [Why can't a string be formed by head String?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59671/121)

Answer (score 2):

I get the same on OS X. The cause of the "problem" can be seen by first evaluating

```
Position[m, 1, {3}]

(* {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 1}, {2, 1, 1}, {3, 1, 1}} *)
```

say what??!!!

But then

```
FullForm[m]
(* List[List[DirectedInfinity[1],DirectedInfinity[1],DirectedInfinity[1]],List[DirectedInfinity[1],1,2],List[DirectedInfinity[1],2,3]] *)
```

...explains it