# Replace expression in series expansion

Tags: replacement, series-expansion

A test case:

I'm trying to replace an expression inside a series expansion:

```
Series[f[x],{x,x0,4}] ./ (x-x0)->h
```

but it still returns

```
f[x0]+f'[x0](x-x0)+.....
```

What am I screwing up here?

Comment: Related: [(71542)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71542/121)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is something which works:

```
Normal@Series[f[x], {x, x0, 4}] /. (x - x0) -> h
```

The reason your attempt doesn't work can be determined by examining the [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html):

```
FullForm@Series[f[x], {x, x0, 4}]

(*SeriesData[x, x0, 
 List[f[x0], Derivative[1][f][x0], 
  Times[Rational[1, 2], Derivative[2][f][x0]], 
  Times[Rational[1, 6], Derivative[3][f][x0]], 
  Times[Rational[1, 24], Derivative[4][f][x0]]], 0, 5, 1]*)
```

`Series` returns a [`SeriesData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesData.html) object which doesn't look anything like what the display output looks like (as can be seen from above), and applying `(x - x0) -> h` doesn't change anything because there is no `(x - x0)` expression inside of the above expression.

Applying [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html) converts the `SeriesData` object into a normal-looking expression, which then gets substituted using the rule `(x - x0) -> h`, giving what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Not the safest way:

```
s = Series[f[x], {x, x0, 4}];
s[[2]] = x - h;
s // Normal
```

$\frac{1}{24} h^4 f^{(4)}(\text{x0})+\frac{1}{6} h^3 f^{(3)}(\text{x0})+\frac{1}{2} h^2 f''(\text{x0})+h f'(\text{x0})+f(\text{x0})$