# Slot # corresponding to subset of a list in select

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, pure-function

Is it possible to use # in the select function preserving the structure of the list?

Here an example of what I mean. Let's say I want to select all the pairs where the first element is 1:

```
data1 = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 4}, {5, 2}};
data2 = {{1, 1}, {1,5}, {3, 5}};
all = {data1, data2};
```

The output of the function would be:

```
{{{1,2},{1,3}},{{1,1},{1,5}}}
```

I tried with Select but I'm not able to preserve the list structure.
Here some (failed) attempt:

```
Select[all, #[[1, 1]] == 1 &]
```

with the output:

```
{{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 4}, {5, 2}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 5}, {3, 5}}}
```

because, as far as I understand, # refers to the elements of the outer list (which are data1 and data2).

Or

```
Select[Flatten[all, 1], #[[1]] == 1 &]
```

with the output

```
{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 1}, {1, 5}}
```

but the list structure is not preserved.

Any tips? I just started using functional programming and I often get stuck on this simple (I assume) stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Select[#, #[[1]] == 1 &] & /@ all
Select[#[[1]] == 1 &] /@ all (* thanks: Mr.Wizard *)
Pick[all, #[[1]] == 1 & /@ # & /@ all]
Pick[all, all[[All, All, 1]], 1]
Map[If[#[[1]] == 1, #, ## &[]] &, all, {2}]
```

all give

> {{{1, 2}, {1, 3}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 5}}}

Comment: Also operator form: `Select[#[[1]] == 1 &] /@ all`

Comment: thank you @Mr.Wizard.

Comment: IMO, `Pick` makes a lot of sense here, good one :)

Comment: Amazing, thank you guys! :D

Comment: @Marius [I like `Pick` too](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/901/121), especially its performance on packed arrays compared to `Select`/`Cases`, but with the caveat that it can at times be confusing, e.g. [(4946)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4946/121), [(59272)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59272/121), [(119223)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119223/121).

Answer (score 7):

```
DeleteCases[all, {Except[1], _}, 2]
```

> {{{1, 2}, {1, 3}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 5}}}

Or, more generally:

```
 DeleteCases[{all, all}, {Except[1], _?AtomQ}, -1] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

At least for the example given:

```
Cases[{1, _}] /@ all
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2}, {1, 3}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 5}}}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

You may use [`Query`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html) with [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html).

```
Query[All, Select[First@# == 1 &]]@all
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2}, {1, 3}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 5}}}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you everyone for your answers, I took all of them and tested their efficiency, below the results with absolute timing, acting on randomly generated lists:

```
data1 = Transpose@{RandomInteger[10, {10^5}], RandomInteger[10, {10^5}]};
data2 = Transpose@{RandomInteger[10, {10^5}], RandomInteger[10, {10^5}]};
all = {data1, data2};

Select[#, #[[1]] == 1 &] & /@ all
0.216706

Select[#[[1]] == 1 &] /@ all
0.218946

Pick[all, #[[1]] == 1 & /@ # & /@ all]
0.404901

Pick[all, all[[All, All, 1]], 1]
0.004603

Map[If[#[[1]] == 1, #, ## &[]] &, all, {2}]
0.356775

Select[#[[1]] == 1 &] /@ all
0.237376

Cases[{1, _}] /@ all
0.078295

DeleteCases[all, {Except[1], _}, 2]
0.104606

Query[All, Select[First@# == 1 &]]@all
0.183894
```